# rails how many foreign keys a table should have

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys, schema, relational-database

I have a rails4 app. I'm having the schema below and will add `post_replies` table that will `belong_to :post_comment` and `post_comment`will `has_many :post_replies`. The replies under comment will always belong to that given comment.

My question is that how many foreign key should be added to post_replies? I will always display them only on `post index page` and new reply will be added with `format_js`. `post_reply` `belongs_to post_comment` for sure, but should I use also both `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :post` ?

current schema:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :post_comments, through: :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_comments
  belongs_to :user
end

class PostComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

planned schema:

```
class PostReply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post_comment #this is needed for sure
  belongs_to :post #do i need this?
  belongs_To :user #and this?
end
```

routes:

```
#current:

resources :posts do
  resources :post_comments, only: [:create, :update, :destroy], module: :posts
end

#and planning to add:

resources :post_comments, only: [] do 
  resources :post_repiles, only: [:create, :update, :destroy], module: :posts
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should belong to User but it wouldn't need to belong to the post if it already belongs to post_comment since you can access post through that model.

Comment: toddmetheny, pls check my comment under Elux91's answer

Comment: your routes look fine to me--are you having a specific problem?

Comment: Yes I'm not sure if I need to nest `post_replies` into `post_comments`. And I'm also not sure if I have to nest the `post_comments` into `posts`

Comment: I don't think you actually need to nest either since you're only using create, update, delete...nesting shouldn't be necessary but also shouldn't hurt anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should name `PostReply` `CommentReply`, because it is a reply to the comment and not to the post directly.

you wouldn't need to save the post_id if you already have the comment id, because the comment already has a relation with the post.

this should work just fine.

```
class CommentReply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post_comment
  belongs_To :user 
end
```

Comment: And what about the routes? I only need `:create`, `:destroy`, and `:update`. How would you organize that in this case?

Comment: whouldn't you need an index route to get comments for a post? If you only have create, destroy and update you have no action that actually gives you the posts, comments.

Comment: I don't need it since comments are displayed only on `posts#index` page (as `post_replies` also will be) and I can simply call `post.post_comments`. But for example for creating a `post_comment` the `post` must be identified, so I route it under that. Now I guess I need to route `post_replies` under `post_comment`.

Comment: sure you would need the same routes for CommentReply as you have for PostReply. In your example routes there is no route for show or index, that's what confused me

Comment: So what I'm doing now with the routes seems to be fine?

Comment: add index and show action to posts routes and add the same routes you have for post_comments for comment_replies